# Continue execution of subsequent stages after timeout of a given stage in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I'm constructing a declarative Jenkins pipeline where i want to have timeout of a stage in a way that subsequent stage continue to run gracefully. I'm sure there are no inter-dependencies between stages in this usecase.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
            stage('Build-1') {
                options {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') 
                }
                steps {
                    echo 'Hello World 1'
                }
            }
            stage('Build-2') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Hello World 2'
                }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, after timeout of stage `Build-1` the pipeline aborts with following message:
`Sending interrupt signal to process
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout`

Here, stage `Build-2` is not executed. Is there a way where despite the timeout in stage `Build-1`, pipeline can continue to run stage `Build-2` gracefully.

I'm referring to following documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
            stage('Build-1') {
                options {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') 
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        try {
                             echo 'Hello World 1'
                        } catch (error) {
                             println "Error happened, continuing"
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
```

You may further examine whether the `error` happened because of timeout, or for other reason.